# How to change displayed button bindings?

Tags: windows, final-fantasy-8

I am playing Final Fantasy 8 on Windows using the Steam edition and an Xbox 360 gamepad. I have configured the buttons so that they map to what I remembered from the console version.

However I am finding sections such as the train decoupling and Zell's limit break very hard to complete because the game is displaying the buttons sequences as <kbd>B1</kbd> and <kbd>B4</kbd> etc. I have no idea which buttons these are on the gamepad.

Is there a way to change the display of the buttons in the game? So that the dialogs will display <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> so that I can easily understand which buttons need to be pressed.

I do understand that I can disconnect the gamepad and use keyboard which will display the actual letter of the keyboard button, but I would much rather use the gamepad.

Currently I have Zell's limit on auto - but I would prefer to input the moves.

Comment: The game is a terrible port, hopefully this post on the Steam Community may be of some use:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/39150/discussions/0/666828127068373740/#c666828127161803275

Comment: @MichaelFrank Looks like a good solution. Do you want to quote the forum post as an answer that I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [this post on the Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/39150/discussions/0/666828127068373740/#c666828127161803275) is about the best answer I could find.

> What I do is I use an Xbox 360 controller with Pinnacle Game Profile (but any other software like this should do the trick).
>
> First I go to My Documents\Square Enix\FFVIII Steam\ and there's the ff8input.cfg. Open it with Notepad, then under "Joystick" replace every value with 0, so gamepad is completely deactivated.
>
> Then I use a Pinnacle profile where I map A button pad to A keyboard, B to B, X to X, Y to Y, LB to L and RB to R. The rest is not that important so map as you see fit. Once it's done I remap the keyboard in the launcher with the profile I made. Be warned, game is based on QWERTY so if you use AZERTY, A is Q. So once in-game, I will have the good input prompt (in my case, B for confirm, A for cancel, X for playing card, Y for menu, R for gunblade trigger / rotate camera right, L for rotate camera left). Pretty useful for Zell tricks.